# What exactly is a RESTful framework?

Tags: frameworks

I am new to REST, I know we can implement the RESTful api in programming languages like C#, but I have no idea what a *RESTful framework* (like [ActiveResource](https://code.google.com/p/implementing-rest/wiki/ActiveResource), [BlueEyes](https://code.google.com/p/implementing-rest/wiki/BlueEyes), etc) rally is.

Thanks.

Comment: Check up [what-exactly-is-restful-programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming)

Comment: Thank you Shlomi, but it is not defining the RESTFUL FRAMEWORK :(